# Explore grid with obstacles

Tags: c, algorithm

I need an algorithm for a robot to explore an n*n grid with obstacles (a maze if you wish). The goal is to explore all the squares without obstacles in them an avoid the squares with obstacles. The trick is that an obstacle forces the robot to change its path causing it to miss the possible free squares behind the obstacle. I can lazily increment/decrement the robot's x/y coordinates to have the robot move in any of the four directions in case there are no obstacles and the robot can traverse a pre-seen path (if needed) in order to reach other free squares. The algorithm should terminate when ALL the free squares were met at least once.

Any simple lazy/efficient way to do this? a pseudo-code will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Technically just a DFS, but you can use a FloodFill Algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is reduceable from [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), and thus is [NP - Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), so you are unlikely to find a polynomial solution that solves the problem optimally and efficiently.

However, You might want to adopt some of the [heuristics and approximations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Heuristic_and_approximation_algorithms)  for TSP, I believe they can be adjusted to this problem as well, since the problem seems very closed to TSP in the first place

**EDIT:**

If finding the *shortest path* is not a requirement, and you want any path, a simple [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) with maintaining a visited set can do. In the step in DFS you come back from the recursion - you move to the previous squares, this way the robot is ensured to explore all squares, if there is a path to all of them.

pseudo code for DFS:

```
search(path,visited,current):
   visited.add(current) 
   for each square s adjacent to current:
      if (s is an obstacle): //cannot go to a square which is an obstacle
         continue
      if (s is not in visited): //no point to go to a node that was already visited
         path.add(s) //go to s
         search(path,visited,current) //recursively visit all squares accesable form s
         //step back from s to current, so you can visit the next neighbor of current.
         path.add(current)
```

invoke with `search([source],{},source)`

Note that optimization heuristics can be used before the `for each` step - the heuristic will just be to reorder the iteration order of the nodes.

Comment: It's not a Salesman Problem: requirement of the shortest path is not applied.

Comment: @DmitryPoroh: I am not sure if it is the case, if their is no shortest path requirement a simple DFS will do.

Comment: @amit: there are situations where the robot needs to visit the previously seen nodes to get to other unseen nodes (like a dead end in a maze case). Does this algorithm (DFS) support such scenarios?

Comment: @SabaAhang: This modification of DFS does exactly that - it comes back the exact path it came from once a dead end was reached, until it finds a new unexplored node - and visits it. Note that DFS is *not* optimal - it will not give you the shortest path. The shortest path is hard to fins, since it is a variation of TSP.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a list of unexplored neighbors. A clever heuristic for which field from the list to visit next can be used to make it more efficient if necessary.

Pseudocode (uses a Stack to keep track of the unexplored neighbors resulting in a DFS):

```
// init
Cell first_cell;
CellStack stack;
stack.push(first_cell);

while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
    Cell currentCell = stack.pop();
    currentCell.markVisisted();
    for(neighbor in currentCell.getNeighbors()) {
        stack.push(neighbor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed I did not mean a list in the traditional sense. Which datastructure to use depends on what heuristic you want to use for traversing. I think a stack might be a good start because it will get you a depth first search.

Comment: Can you please provide a psudocode? I don't quiet understand how...I'm using a model checking tool called uppaal and it only supports the very basic expression/loop...of C

Comment: @SabaAhang I've added some. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way of the problem solve is recursive (go to nearest free cell). With following additional heuristic: go to the nearest free cell with minimal free neighbours (prefer stubs).

Pseudocode:

```
// init:
for (cell in all_cells) {
    cell.weight = calc_neighbors_number(cell);
}

path = [];

void calc_path(cell)
{
    cell.visited = true;
    path.push_back(cell);
    preferred_cell = null;
    for (cell in cell.neighbors)
        if (cell.visited) {
            continue;
        }
        if (preferred_cell == null || preferred_cell.weight > cell.weight)
           preferred_cell = cell;
    }
    if (preferred_cell != null) {
        calc_path(preferred_cell);
    }
}

// Start algotithm:
calc_path(start);
```